# How to formulate the 1 dimensional time-dependent Schrodinger’s equation from a given function?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

> Assuming $f(t) =e^{−iωt}$, formulate the 1 dimensional time-dependent Schrodinger’s equation.

I started solving the problem as
\begin{align}
  E &= hf, \tag1\label{eq:1}\\
  E &= ħw, \tag2\label{eq:2}\\
  \frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t}
    &=-iωf(t). \tag3\label{eq:3}
\end{align}

Then I solved \eqref{eq:2} and \eqref{eq:3} to get
$$\frac{-iE}{ħ}f(t)=\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t}. \tag4 $$

Now I am not sure how to continue from here to get the time-dependent Schrodinger’s equation.

Comment: The derivation you're showing *is* the time derivation. The time dependent wavefunction is $\Psi (x, t) = f(t)\psi(x) = e^{\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}}\psi(x)$ and setting t=0 gives you $\Psi (x, t) = \psi(x)$ which is where the time-independent equation comes from. IDK how you get that going backwards thought without just knowing that.

Comment: Unless what you're actually looking for is this piece: $f(t) = e^{\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}}$ and that just comes from knowing that the only function whos derivative yields the original function multiplied by some constant is the exponential function.